# Requirements for Android Map Application

Tags: android, google-maps, opengl-es

I want to develop an Android Application the gives the distinct map of my college. Can anyone tell me what it takes to develop such a service. Is OpenGL necessary for such an application? The basic idea is to have something like Google maps that shows where the user is and directions.

My college is situated in a hilly region so the google maps images are not very clear. Can I use Google Maps and perhaps modify it in some way so as to build a crisp clear application? Or is it better to start afresh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL isn't necessary for a mapping application (although it can be used), in fact most mapping applications, Google maps included, use pre-rendered image "tiles".  Each tile covers a set geographical area and includes all the information that the user may need.

A good application for generating tiles is [TileMill](http://mapbox.com/tilemill/).  Tilemill needs mapping data to generate the tiles and a good source for this data is  [OpenSteetMap](http://planet.openstreetmap.org/).  Once you have created your custom tiles you can use the android location api to get the users location and display the relevant tiles with a marker.

Another option is to use something like [Mapp](http://mapp.android-libraries.com/) although this costs money.

Comment: ok, is there any way i could provide my own overhead images as tiles, instead of relying on data from open street map?

Comment: yes, you could just create tiles from aerial or satellite imagery or combine it with existing mapping information from OpenStreetMap with whatever styling you desire.  TileMill supports using your own raster data to create tiles.

Comment: is there any free way? It seems TileMill is not free.

Comment: TileMill the program to generate tiles is free to use, you only have to pay if you want MapBox, the company who makes TileMill, to store your map tiles which i'm guessing you don't for your app.

Comment: ok, but the after the map is created, how do i run it on the server without using MapBox paid service?

Comment: If the mapping application is just for your college you could include all of the tiles in the android app itself.  All your app would have to do is display the correct tile based on the users location.